# Populate comma separated string to multi select ListBox in Asp.net - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, multi-select

I have a List Box which i want to get selected from a comma separated string but my code is not working.

## ASPX:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">aaa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">bbb</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">ccc</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">ddd</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">eee</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">fff</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

## ASPX.CS: (Code)

```
string listboxvalues = "2,1,5";
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (string category in listboxvalues.ToString().Split(','))
    {
        if (category != ListBox1.Items[i].Value) continue;
            ListBox1.Items[i].Selected = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

## Expected Result: (The expected result is what i am expecting but the code is not selecting anything)

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">aaa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Selected="True">bbb</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">ccc</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">ddd</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Selected="True">eee</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">fff</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: What do you mean by my code is not working? This code as it is seems to select 1 2 and 5 in the `ListBox`

Comment: The expected result is what i am expecting but the code is not selecting anything

Comment: Where did you place the code behind? in the `Page_Load`? I just tested it and it worked... Are you sure there's nothing else that deselects the items?

Answer (score 1):

ASPX.CS: (Code)

```
string listboxvalues = "2,1,5";

//declare a list

List<string> items = new List<string>()

for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (string category in listboxvalues.ToString().Split(','))
    {
        if (category != ListBox1.Items[i].Value) continue;
            items.Add(category);
            break;
    }
}

//then in your ListBox1

listBox1.DataSource = items;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Item";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Comment: `List<string> items` not have ***Item or Value*** properties?